# How to Detect Email Bounces with IIS 6 with C#

Tags: c#, email, iis-6

Just as the question says.

I am using IIS 6 to send emails out from my Windows Server with C#.  I want to detect bounces with C# from the SMTP email server.  Right now, all the bounces get sent to a Gmail account.  I could just check and parse each email in that account, but I was wondering if there is any easier way like hooking up a windows service or something to the IIS 6 SMTP server.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: IIS6 = Windows Server 2003 = [Mainstream support ended 3 years ago](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/default.aspx?LN=en-us&x=13&y=7&p1=3198) = maybe you should consider upgrading.

Comment: IIS6 = Windows Server 2008 R2 = Stop making assumptions and just be polite enough and try answering the question.

Comment: Considering that IIS 7 shipped with Server 2008, and IIS 7.5 shipped with Server 2008 R2, I'd be interested to know how you managed to install IIS 6, and why. Since IIS 7 was a complete rewrite of IIS 6, being clear about the version could affect the polite answers you get.

Comment: Your right.  7.0 in its complete rewrite doesn't actually come with a SMTP server.  You must use 6.0 to get access to your own SMTP server.  Unless you can convince me otherwise, I have been using 6.0 to direct 1000's of emails to the correct places.  Though, even if I was using 6.0 or 7.0, do you know a way to actually get access to the bounces through code?

Comment: I didn't even realize it was possible to install IIS 6 on a server that came bundled with a later version of IIS. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I know little about the IIS6 SMTP server, but based on what I know about SMTP in general, I doubt you're going to have much luck. Your message to joe@foo.com gets forwarded from server to server until it ends up at the foo.com SMTP server, which then responds to the reply-to address that the "joe" mailbox doesn't exist. That server may have no direct contact with your SMTP server at all.

As a result, there's no opportunity for the IIS6 SMTP server to receive any information about the bounced message. I think your existing idea of polling the inbox for the reply-to address is probably going to be your best bet.